# Suppress Outlook pop-up allow access

Tags: powershell, outlook

When running the following PowerShell code:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application   
$Stores = $Outlook.Session.Stores 
$Accounts = $Outlook.Session.Accounts
$Accounts | Select-Object DisplayName, UserName, SmtpAddress, ExchangeMailboxServerName, ExchangeMailboxServerVersion
```

A security warning pops-up:

[image]

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/263084) there are ways around this. For instance, one can `Create a COM Add-in for Outlook` instead of using the `Outlook COM Object` as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240768). Another example of a custom `COM Add-in for Outlook` is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235231/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-reading-outlook-message-from-c-sharp-pr) on StackOverflow but for another language.

Using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` should make this [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175803/how-to-access-application-property-in-vsto-outlook-add-in-outside-of-thisaddin-c), No? Can someone explain to me how this is done with PowerShell? It would be great if we could avoid this pop-up as it will only confuse users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Outlook security alert when reading outlook message from C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235231/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-reading-outlook-message-from-c-sharp-pr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a [workaround](http://kb.politemail.com/?p=1039) by editing the registry as local administrator before running the code:

```
Function Remove-OutlookSecurityPromptHC {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param()

    if (Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook') {
        Write-Verbose 'Found MS Outlook 2010'

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security')) {
            New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security' | Out-Null
        }
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security' -Name ObjectModelGuard -Value 2
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security' -Name PromptOOMSend -Value 2
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security' -Name AdminSecurityMode -Value 3
        Write-Verbose 'Outlook warning suppressed'
    }

    if (Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook') {
        Write-Verbose 'Found MS Outlook 2007'

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security')) {
            New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security' | Out-Null
        }
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security' -Name ObjectModelGuard -Value 2
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security' -Name PromptOOMSend -Value 2
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security' -Name AdminSecurityMode -Value 3
        Write-Verbose 'Outlook warning suppressed'
    }
}

Remove-OutlookSecurityPromptHC -Verbose
```

After running this code a reboot/logoff might be needed before it becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make sure an up-to-date anti-virus product is installed on the machine (if you can control the client environment) or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) or [Clickyes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/) to work around the security prompts. See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for more details.

Comment: There's no Powershell only (without 3rd party code) option to suppress this message?

Comment: Unfortunately not my friend, a little janky design if you ask me.