# Suppressing Outlook "This program is trying to access E-mail" pop-up for specific powershell script only

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, outlook-2010, office-automation

When I run the following powershell script to send an e-mail :

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "H:\TP65655\IDX CVA\UAT" -Include *.idx -Recurse | Where {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}
$atts = $file.fullname
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "email@domain.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Testing E-mail Automation"
$Mail.Body = "UAT TEST"
Try
{
    $Mail.Attachments.Add($atts)
    $Mail.Send()
    Write-Host "Mail Sent Successfully"
    Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "File Not Attached Successfully, Please Try Again"
    Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
    Exit
}
```

The following pops up from Outlook :

[Pop Up from Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1caJ.jpg)

Is there any way I can remove this without changing the programmatic access in Trust Center to "Never" as this is an organization desktop and that option is not feasible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress Outlook pop-up allow access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302096/suppress-outlook-pop-up-allow-access)

Comment: @OwainEsau No. Changing the security settings is not feasible according to our organization policy

Comment: Why are you using a COM object to send a mail instead of send-mailmessage?

Comment: @bluuf I'm trying to bypass the SMTP procedure to send it using the outlook application itself

Answer (score 0):

You get a standard security prompt in Outlook. Your options are:

1. Use the [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) component which allows to disable such warnings at run-time dynamically.
2. Use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. It doesn't throw security warnings or pop-ups. Or just consider using any wrapper around a low-level API such as Redemption.
3. Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted `Application` object. COM add-ins don't trigger such security prompts.
4. Deploy security settings via GPO.
5. Install any antivirus software with latest updates.

You may find the ["A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-email-message-on-your-behalf) article in MSDN helpful.